# Why subprocess.Popen returncode differs for similar commands with bash

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, dash-shell

Why

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", "timeout -s KILL 1 sleep 5 2>/dev/null"])
p.wait()
print(p.returncode)
```

returns

```
[stderr:] /bin/bash: line 1: 963663 Killed                  timeout -s KILL 1 sleep 5 2> /dev/null
[stdout:] 137
```

when

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", "timeout -s KILL 1 sleep 5"])
p.wait()
print(p.returncode)
```

returns

```
[stdout:] -9
```

If you change bash to dash, you'll get 137 in both cases. I know that -9 is KILL code and 137 is 128 + 9. But seems weird for similar code to get different returncode.

Happens on Python 2.7.12 and python 3.4.3

Looks like `Popen.wait()` does not call `Popen._handle_exitstatus` https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.4/Lib/subprocess.py#L1468 when using `/bin/bash` but I could not figure out why.

Comment: Looks like `timeout` is Linux specific, by the way.  I get a return code of 127 with both code versions on 2.7.10 and 3.6.0 on OS X.

Answer (score 4):

This is due to the fact how `bash` executes `timeout` with or without redirection/pipes or any other bash features:

- With redirection

  1. `python` starts `bash`
  2. `bash` starts `timeout`, monitors the process and does pipe handling.
  3. `timeout` transfers itself into a new process group and starts `sleep`
  4. After one second, `timeout` sends `SIGKILL` into its process group
  5. As the process group died, `bash` returns from waiting for `timeout`, sees the `SIGKILL` and prints the message pasted above to `stderr`. It then sets its own exit status to 128+9 (a behaviour simulated by `timeout`).
- Without redirection

  1. `python` starts `bash`.
  2. `bash` sees that it has nothing to do on its own and calls `execve()` to effectively replace itself with `timeout`.
  3. `timeout` acts as above, the whole process group dies with `SIGKILL`.
  4. `python` get's an exit status of `9` and does some mangling to turn this into `-9` (`SIGKILL`)

In other words, without redirection/pipes/etc. `bash` withdraws itself from the call-chain. Your second example looks like `subprocess.Popen()` is executing `bash`, yet effectively it does not. `bash` is no longer there when `timeout` does its deed, which is why you don't get any messages and an unmangled exit status.

If you want consistent behaviour, use `timeout --foreground`; you'll get an exit status of 124 in both cases.

I don't know about dash; yet suppose it does not do any `execve()` trickery to effectively replace itself with the only program it's executing. Therefore you always see the mangled exit status of 128+9 in dash.

*Update*: `zsh`shows the same behaviour, while it drops out even for simple redirections such as `timeout -s KILL 1 sleep 5 >/tmp/foo` and the like, giving you an exit status of -9. `timeout -s KILL 1 sleep 5 && echo $?` will give you status 137 in `zsh` also.

Comment: Sorry but I do not completly understood. If in first case timeout return 128+9  why in second case on step 4 python gets an exit status of 9. Since timeout is the one responsible for 128+9 code, shouldn't it pass this code in second case on step 4?